# How to set border color in jetpack compose BasicTextField?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I use `BasicTextField` from `package androidx.compose.foundation.text` and it has a default grey field color as visible here:
[image]

I do not want this grey highlight, therefore I want to set the backgroundColor completely to black:

```
BasicTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Black)
)
```

But this does take effect only partially as visible here
[image]

There is a border still having grey color.

It is ok to keep the border dimensions, but I would like to have a complete black background as here
[image]

How can I manage this?

Edit: I tried to add a `border()` modifier with `color = Color.Black` -  in vain.

Comment: why are you trying to pass `R.color.black`? You should use `Color.Black`. Or is this some extension of yours? `Modifier.background(Color.Black)` works fine to me

Comment: Both have the same value, we can replace with 'Color.Black'

Comment: which version of compose are you using?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti  compose_ver = "1.1.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the code of your Composable,please try:

```
@Composable
fun Simple() {
    var v by remember { mutableStateOf("Text") }
    Row(Modifier.background(Color.Black).padding(16.dp),verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
        Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "back",tint = Color.White)
        BasicTextField(
            v, { v = it },
            Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(start = 13.dp),
            textStyle = TextStyle(Color.White, 13.sp),
            singleLine = true
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Shrinking you example         @Composable
        fun Simple() {
            var v by remember { mutableStateOf("Text") }
                BasicTextField(
                    v, { v = it },
                    Modifier
                        .background(Color.Black)
                        .padding(start = 13.dp),
                    textStyle = TextStyle(Color.White, 13.sp),
                    singleLine = true
                )
        }
did the same.

Comment: yes, I'm just writing according to the picture, add Icons arrowback